# make required option for inputs depending on a checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox as following :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bacLibre" id="bacLibre" ng-model="bacLibre">
```

and other inputs as following :

```
<div id="bacSection" ng-show="!bacLibre">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="regionalScore">
              {{'FME_CANDIDATURE.EDUCATION_INFORMATIONS.REGIONAL_SCORE' | translate}}:
            </label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="20" step="0.01" name="regionalScore" id="regionalScore" class="form-control input-lg"
                   ng-model="candidature.regionalScore"
                   required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="bacSecondYearFirstSemScore">
              {{'FME_CANDIDATURE.EDUCATION_INFORMATIONS.BAC_SECOND_YEAR_FIRST_SEM_SCORE' | translate}}:
            </label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="20" step="0.01" name="bacSecondYearFirstSemScore" id="bacSecondYearFirstSemScore"
                   class="form-control input-lg"
                   ng-model="candidature.bacSecondYearFirstSemScore"
                   required>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

as you can see all the inputs are required I want when I check that checkbox to change the state of all the inputs in that `<div id="bacSection">` to not required, and then when I uncheck that checkbox to make all the inputs required.

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a directive `ng-required`, use that on the input with a expression that gets changed

`<<input type="number" min="0" max="20" step="0.01" name="bacSecondYearFirstSemScore" id="bacSecondYearFirstSemScore"
                   class="form-control input-lg"
                   ng-model="candidature.bacSecondYearFirstSemScore"
                   ng-required='bacLibre'>`